# jmeter How to run alert command in JSR223 sampler

Tags: jmeter

How to I create an alert in javascript. I am using JSR223 but does not like
alert("test");

Question is why does it not recognise it as I have set language to javascript and what would I have to do?

Comment: what do you mean by alert? (`alert("test");` is an interactive dialog box, while in JMeter you should not be doing anything interactively, since in most cases you'd want to run it for many many threads, so you'd have 100s of dialogs)

Comment: Also JavaScript included in Jmeter is server-side JS, based on Rhino: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_(JavaScript_engine)

Answer (score 1):

1. As per [JMeter Project Main Page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

   > JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

   so JMeter won't execute client-side JavaScript.
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 users are encouraged to use JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language for scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) as Groovy performance is much better comparing to the other languages.

Assuming all above you can create a pop-UI using the following Groovy code in the JSR223 Sampler:

```
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 'test', 'JMeter says:', javax.swing.JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter JSR223 Groovy Demo]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Such a great explanation ,thanks again. I have read a lot of articles  but this really explains it with the bold etc, so thanks so much.

Comment: Hi, Is there anyway to call javascript so for example if it does not run javascript  but the javascript  I can get to, could I call it myself one by one?